# What is wrong with my gradient descent implementation for Linear regression in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, regression, gradient-descent

I've been trying to refresh my fundamental knowledge of stats, so I tried to implement simple linear regression in python using gradient descent.

The code correctly minimizes the MSE, however it does so by making a straight horizontal line across the dataset
[image]

I'm not sure if this is a hyper-parameter issue, if it is I can't find good values for it, or its because an error in code.

I have been suspecting that this is due to the error simply being train_y - pred_y
so the errors cancel each other out on each side.

I tried to use absolute error or mse error however I'm not sure how the derivative would work in this case, or if this is the right way to go.

The first function is the gradient descent implementation the rest is for the animation.

```
def gradientDescent(train_X,train_y,lr,epochs,init_slope=1,init_intercept=0.1):
    if len(train_X) != len(train_y):
        raise Exception("train_X and train_Y must be the same length.")

    train_X = np.array(train_X)
    train_y = np.array(train_y)
    n = len(train_X)

    slope = init_slope
    intercept = init_intercept
    for e in range(epochs):
        pred_y = slope * train_X + intercept 
        errors = (train_y - pred_y)
        mse = errors.mean()

        slope -= lr * (-2/n) * np.sum(train_X * errors)
        intercept -= lr * (-2/n) * np.sum(errors)

    return mse, slope, intercept

def generateLine(slope,intercept,start,end):
    x = [i for i in range(int(start),int(end))]
    y = [slope*xi + intercept for xi in x]
    return x, y



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

from sklearn import datasets


n_samples = 10
n_outliers = 2

train_X, train_y, coef = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=n_samples, n_features=1,
                                      n_informative=1, noise=20,
                                      coef=True, random_state=0)


lr = 0.03
epochs = 1000

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([0], [0])

plt.plot(train_X,train_y,'o')

slope=0
intercept = 0
def animate(i):
    
    global slope, intercept
    if i == 1:
        mse, slope, intercept = gradientDescent(train_X,train_y,lr=lr, epochs = 1,init_slope= np.random.random(), init_intercept=np.random.random())

    mse, slope, intercept = gradientDescent(train_X,train_y,lr=lr,epochs=1,init_slope = slope, init_intercept = intercept)
    line_x, line_y = generateLine(slope, intercept,min(min(train_X),min(train_y)),max(max(train_X),max(train_y)))

    line.set_xdata(line_x)
    line.set_ydata(line_y) 
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch: {i}, MSE = {mse:.6f}')

    return line,

def init():
    line.set_ydata([0])
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=range(1, epochs), init_func=init, interval=100, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the issue was the shape of the train_X was (10,1) so when I multiplied with the errors to find the derivative of the slope, it produced the wrong result.

I fixed it by flattening the train_X